# webBrowser c#. как автоматически нажать на кнопку и вставить текст в текстовое поле?

Tags: c#

здравствуйте, есть два баттона, первый нажимает в браузете на кнопку:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://vk.com/muj1k");
    HtmlElementCollection elmCol;
    elmCol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

    foreach (HtmlElement elmBtn in elmCol)
    {
        if (elmBtn.GetAttribute("className") == "button_link cut_left")
        {
            elmBtn.InvokeMember("Click");                
        }
    }
}
```

второй вставляет в текстовое поле нужный текст:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElementCollection elmCol;
    elmCol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
    foreach (HtmlElement elmBtn in elmCol)
    {
        if (elmBtn.GetAttribute("className") == "im_editable")
        {
            elmBtn.InnerText = "text";
        }
    }
}
```

по отдельности они отлично работают, но как сделать так, чтоб при нажатии на 1 баттон сразу жалась кнопка и заполнялось текстовое поле?

Comment: А с vk API совсем не судьба? Потому что мне кажется, что вы создаёте самому себе трудности.

Comment: Вероятно троянcкого бота пишет. ;-)

Comment: не бота, просто для саморазвития. так что, идей нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://vk.com/muj1k");
    HtmlElementCollection elmCol;

    elmCol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

    foreach (HtmlElement elmBtn in elmCol)
    {
        if (elmBtn.GetAttribute("className") == "button_link cut_left")
        {
            elmBtn.InvokeMember("Click");
            break;                
        }
    }

    elmCol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");

    foreach (HtmlElement elmBtn in elmCol)
    {
        if (elmBtn.GetAttribute("className") == "im_editable")
        {
            elmBtn.InnerText = "text";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Или с использование LINQ:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://vk.com/muj1k");

    var elmCol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

    var elmBtn = elmCol.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttribute("className") == "button_link cut_left");
    if (elmBtn != null) 
    {
        elmBtn.InvokeMember("Click");                
    }

    elmCol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");

    elmBtn = elmCol.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttribute("className") == "im_editable");
    if (elmBtn != null)
    {
        elmBtn.InnerText = "text";
    }
}
```